# Is there a way to make angled corners using CSS3 on an element?

Tags: css

Trying to get this "angled cutout" look. I'd prefer not use any hacks with pseudo elements if possible.

[image]

HTML would be something simple like:

```
   <span>Hello World</span>
```

CSS:

```
   span {
     // some crazy new css-3 rule?
   }
```

I don't care about older browsers and the solution must be responsive.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want "hacks with pseudo elements"? (since you don't care about older browsers, I don't see why not?)

Comment: Is my answer good enough to be accepted?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such *crazy* rules in CSS3 (and none in CSS4*), so you can either create a SVG, or use the unwanted pseudo (or 2 extra inner elements, which IMHO is worse)

Here is the simplest, less hackiest, solution with pseudo

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}
span::before, span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: -1;
}
span::before {
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: skewX(40deg);
}
span::after {
  top: 50%;
  border-top: none;
  transform: skewX(-40deg);
}

/* second span */
span ~ span {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello World</span>
<br>
<span>Hello World</span>
```

---

- In CSS4 we might get an option of wider range of [border shapings](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-4/#propdef-corner-shape)

Answer (score 0):

I make an example for cutout corner with `CSS3`.

```css
.quote {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.q{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding:10px;
  margin:100px;
  width:100px;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
}
.quote:after {
  background: inherit;
  bottom: -11px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 200%;
  left: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  transform: skewX(-35deg);
  transform-origin: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.quote:before {
  background: inherit;
  top: -11px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 200%;
  left: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  transform: skewX(35deg);
  transform-origin: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.q:after{
      background: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  top:20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  transform: skewX(-35deg);
  transform-origin: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.q:before{
  background: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  top:-00px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  transform: skewX(35deg);
  transform-origin: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="q">
    <span class="quote">Hello World!!</span>
</div>
```